# struts 1 validation isn't working

Tags: java, validation, struts-1, struts-validation

i have troubles with form validation, when i press submit button, with empty fields, the validate() method isn't called, but i get javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate , also when i press cancel button things go the same, here is some code:

```
<html:form action="/AddNews.do" >
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="newsTitle"> <bean:message
                        key="addnews.label.title" />
                </label>

                <html:text property="newsTitle" size="40" maxlength="20" />
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label pull-left" for="newsDate"> <bean:message
                        key="addnews.label.date" />
                </label>
                <html:textarea property="newsDate" cols="50" rows="10" />
            </div>

            <bean:message key="addnews.label.brief" />
            <html:textarea property="newsBrief" cols="50" rows="10" />
            <bean:message key="addnews.label.content" />
            <html:textarea property="newsContent" cols="50" rows="10" />
            <bean:message key="addnews.button.submit" />

            <html:submit>
                <bean:message key="addnews.button.submit" />
            </html:submit>

            <html:cancel ><bean:message key="addnews.button.cancel"/></html:cancel>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <html:errors/>
</html:form>

public class AddNewsAction  extends Action{
    private static Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(ListNewsAction.class);
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        NewsDaoImpl dao = new NewsDaoImpl();
        AddNewsForm addForm = (AddNewsForm)form;
        addForm.validate(mapping, request);
        News newsInstance = new News();
        try {
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(newsInstance, addForm);
            dao.addNews(newsInstance, CheckLocale.checkLocale(request));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        } catch (DAOLogicException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        } catch (DAOTechnicException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
            if( this.isCancelled( request ) )
            {
                System.out.println( "About to forward the cancel!" );
                return mapping.findForward( "cancel");
                }   
            else{
                return mapping.findForward("listNews");
            }
    }
}
```

some code from struts-config.xml:

```
<form-bean name="AddNewsForm" type="by.blabla.form.AddNewsForm" />
<action path="/AddNewsPage"
            type="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy"

            parameter="/pages/addNews.jsp" />

        <action path="/AddNews"
            type="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy" name="AddNewsForm"
            validate="true" cancellable="true" input="/pages/addNews.jsp">
            <forward name="cancel" path="/listNews.do"/>
            <forward name="listNews" redirect="true" path="/listNews.do" />
        </action>



<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
        <set-property property="pathnames"
            value="/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml,
               /WEB-INF/validation.xml" />
    </plug-in>
```

Form:

```
public class AddNewsForm extends ActionForm{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4359805626315443538L;
    private String newsTitle;
    private Date newsDate;
    private String newsBrief;
    private String newsContent;


    public String getNewsTitle() {
        return newsTitle;
    }

    public void setNewsTitle(String newsTitle) {
        this.newsTitle = newsTitle;
    }

    public Date getNewsDate() {
        return newsDate;
    }


    public void setNewsDate(Date newsDate) {
        this.newsDate = newsDate;
    }
    public String getNewsBrief() {
        return newsBrief;
    }

    public void setNewsBrief(String newsBrief) {
        this.newsBrief = newsBrief;
    }

    public String getNewsContent() {
        return newsContent;
    }

    public void setNewsContent(String newsContent) {

        this.newsContent = newsContent;
    }

    @Override
    public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping,
            HttpServletRequest request) {

                ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

                if( getNewsTitle() == null || ("".equals(getNewsTitle()))) {
                   errors.add("error.title",
                      new ActionMessage("error.required"));
                }

                if( getNewsDate() == null || ("".equals(getNewsDate()))) {
                   errors.add("error.date",
                       new ActionMessage("error.required"));
                }
                if( getNewsBrief() == null || ("".equals(getNewsBrief()))) {
                       errors.add("error.brief",
                           new ActionMessage("error.required"));
                    }
                if( getNewsContent() == null || ("".equals(getNewsContent()))) {
                       errors.add("error.content",
                           new ActionMessage("error.required"));
                    }
                return errors;
            }
    }
```

i also have validation.xml and validation-rules.xml in web-inf directory and tryed to use ValidatorForm insted of ActionForm but nothing changed, 
so any suggestions would be very appreciated

**Edit:** full stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [/struts-blank-lastweekLATEST] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate] with root cause
org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: No value specified for 'java.sql.Date'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.handleMissing(AbstractConverter.java:310)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.DateTimeConverter.convertToType(DateTimeConverter.java:323)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.convert(AbstractConverter.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.ConverterFacade.convert(ConverterFacade.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.convert(ConvertUtilsBean.java:470)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1006)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:830)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:433)
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:473)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PopulateActionForm.populate(PopulateActionForm.java:50)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractPopulateActionForm.execute(AbstractPopulateActionForm.java:60)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: What's the complete stacktrace you get?

Comment: @Michael, added in edit

Comment: ok, i solve it somehow

Comment: I guess when you've declared the field `newsDate`, you've created an import statement `java.sql.Date`. That's the wrong type, you must use `java.util.Date`. I'd recomment to learn how to read stack traces, in most cases they are pretty helpful :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the Validator plug-in, you need to do the following tasks:

1. Create your form class by extending the class `org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorActionForm` instead of the normal `org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm`.
2. Add the Validator plug-in in the `struts-config.xml` file (Plug-in Definitions).

   ```
   <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
       <set-property property="pathnames"
           value="/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml,/WEB-INF/validation.xml" />
   </plug-in>
   ```
3. Define the validation rules to apply to your form fields by configuring
   the `validation.xml` file.
4. Modify and adjust the `struts-config.xml` file and the message resources.